# Mongoose custom error message in path validation

Tags: validation, mongoose

I have a complex data type that I wish to store in a mongoose model. Suppose my schema is as follows

```
dataSchema : {
    name : 'string',
    body : 'object'
}
```

During `save` or `findOneAndUpdate` for my models I would like to perform some validation on the body using a parser that throws custom error messages.

My current handling of the validation is as follows:

```
dataSchema.path('body').validate(function(body,callback){

    // Attempt to parse the structure
    try{
        parse(body)
        callback(true)
    } catch(me) {
        // callback(me) // does not help!
        callback(false)
    }


}, 'Unable to parse body')
```

alongside

```
dataSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {
    this.options.runValidators = true;
    next();
});
```

Which seems to work as expected. However I would like to customise the error message from the validator (currently: 'Unable to parse body') so that I can propagate the error information `me` in the catch statement.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mongoose documentation for [validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html), down at the bottom of the page it conveniently states

> Now that we've covered validation, let's take a look at how you might
>   handle advanced validation with Mongoose's middleware.

which can be found [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).

Using middleware my problem is solved using a helper function

```
function validate(rec, next){
    try{
       // Attempt to parse the object
       parse(rec.object)
       next()
    } catch(me){
       // report fail - Note should use mongoose ValidationError class
       next(me)
    }

}
```

Which is wired up using the following hooks:

```
dataSchema.pre('save',function(next){ validate(this, next) }
dataSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next){ validate(this, next) }
```